# Ajax load more button in Recent posts widget

Tags: posts, wp-query, widgets, jquery, ajax

I create Recent posts widget and i trying to create load more button for it to get more Recent posts links by ajax ,is there any tutorial for how to make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [WordPress's documentation on AJAX](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Ajax_on_the_Viewer-Facing_Side)

In your theme or plugin, you'll want to have code like:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_load_recent', 'my_load_recent_posts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_load_recent', 'my_load_recent_posts');
function my_load_recent_posts() {
    $args = array(
        /* Arguments go here, i.e. how many posts to get */
    );
    query_posts($args); /* [1] */

    /* Header wrap output */
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); /* [2] */
        /* Output for each post */
    endwhile; else :
        /* Output for if there are no posts to get */
    endif;
    /* Footer wrap output */

    wp_reset_query();
}
```

[1] [`query_posts()` documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)

[2] [Wordpress loop documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)

Then to reach this function you'll want to have on your front end, assuming you're using jQuery:

```
$.ajax(ajax_url/* [3] */, {
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
       action: 'my_load_recent',
    },
    success: function(response) {
        /* handling of the output returned by PHP function */
    },
    error: function() {
        /* what to do if there's a server error, like 404
    }
});
```

[3] See WordPress's documentation on AJAX to generate the `ajax_url`: "As [this article](http://wphardcore.com/2010/5-tips-for-using-ajax-in-wordpress/) suggests, use [wp_localize_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) to make the URL available to your script, and generate it using this expression: admin_url('admin-ajax.php')"

Comment: this is good but i need to create button called Load more when clicked get me the next posts links list ,like twitter.com

Comment: You can do this easily with my instructions, you make your button trigger the JavaScript I wrote. Then you have the PHP output `li`'s with linked titles using `the_permalink()` and `the_title()`, then you append the response to the widget `ul` in your success handler. You may want to pass an offset in your AJAX call, so that you can load posts more than once.

Comment: sorry but how to pass an offset in my AJAX call?

Comment: In the data parameter in your AJAX, you would pass something like: `offset: 0` or `offset: 5` and then in your PHP function you get that information using `$_POST['offset']`. Then you utilize that in your `query_posts()` array, by setting `offset => $_POST['offset']` Just be sure to maintain the value, maybe as data on the load more button element, and increment it everytime you load more posts.

Comment: sorry but last one question :), how to increment the  offset var everytime i load more posts?

Comment: I'm assuming you're going to be using a data value on the add more button to track offset. So in your success handler, you'll want to have a line like: `$('#load-more-btn').data('offset', $('#load-more-btn').data('offset') + 5);` Then your $.ajax function passes the data parameter: `{ action: 'my_load_recent', offset: $('#load-more-btn').data('offset') }`